# Why does $T(x^2) \neq T(x\cdot x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Given linear operator $T : \mathbb{R}_2[x] \rightarrow : \mathbb{R}_2[x]$, defined as:

$$T(x^2) = 2-6x\\T(x) = -3\\T(1) = 0$$

I know that if $x_1 = x_2$, then $f(x_1)$ = $f(x_2)$. However:

$$p_1 = x^2\\ p_2 = x\cdot x \\ \Downarrow\\ p_1 = p_2 \\ \Downarrow \\ T(x^2) = 2-6x = T(x\cdot x) = T(\underbrace{x + x +...+x}_{x \text{ times}}) = \underbrace{T(x) + T(x) +...+T(x)}_{x \text{ times}} = -3x \underset{\text{Contradiction}}{=} 2-6x $$

Why?

Comment: Here's the rub: what *exactly* do you mean by $T(x \cdot x) = T(x) + T(x) + \ldots + T(x)$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Forgot to explain it. I'll update the question.

Comment: If $x\cdot x=x^2$, then there is a problem with your notation. As polynomials, $p_1=p_2$. I don't understand why $T(x\cdot x)=T(x+\cdots +x)$.

Comment: Linear operator preserves addition and scalar multiplication and may be defined on spaces where vector multiplication is not defined, and even when it is defined it may not be respected by linear operator

Comment: OK, now what *exactly* do you mean by $x \cdot x = x + x + \ldots+ x$? For example, what would this mean if $x = \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: To expand on JWTanner's comment a bit, linearity of operators is _only_ with respect to constants in the underlying space (in this case, $\mathbb{R_2[x]}$); $x$ is not a constant and you can't treat it as though it were. In other words, if $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p, q\in\mathbb{R}_2[x]$, then $T(ap+bq)=aT(p)+bT(q)$. But what you want to do is essentially say that $T(xp)$ should equal $xT(p)$.  It's better to think of $x$ as a _formal_ quantity here; it doesn't have to represent a number at all. For instance, nothing here prevents $x$ from being, say, a 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to write 
$$  T(x \cdot x)  =  T(\underbrace{x + x + \cdots + x}_{\text{$x$ times}})  $$
which should help clarify that this expression can only be sensible if $x$ is a non-negative integer.  $x$ is not any kind of integer; you declared it to be an indeterminate when you wrote "$\mathbb{R}_2[x]$".

Comment: This still doesn't work if the operator will be above the natural numbers though, which makes the above expression well-defined.

Comment: @daedsidog : When you say "above the natural numbers", there is no "$x$", so you are describing $T:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @daedsidog : Do you believe that an indeterminate somehow takes values in the coefficient set?  An indeterminate in a ring extension (like $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$) is a placeholder that satisfies ring operations.  It does not have, take, or receive values.  To specialize an indeterminate to a value requires a different "evaluation operator", which maps the intedeterminant to an element of a (super-)ring of the coefficient ring.

Comment: I meant $T:\mathbb{N}_2[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_2[x]$.

Comment: @daedsidog : The indeterminant, $x$, is *not* an instance of and does *not* take values in the coefficient set.  It, $\mathbb{N}_2[x]$, is an extension, so $x$ is none of the coefficients.   (This comment disregards perverse redundancies, like $(\mathbb{R}_2[x])[x]$.)